# Loop array time C# Winforms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, loops, time

Let's say I have a password array...

> ```
>       var pass = new int[5];
>         pass[0] = 111111;
>         pass[1] = 222222;
>         pass[2] = 333333;
>         pass[3] = 444444;
>         pass[4] = 555555;
> ```

And a validation of the current time. For example you have a schedule of 7:30:00 AM to 11:30:00 AM, and you cannot get your password if it's not yet 7:30, and if it's already past 11:30. But between that time frame, it's okay, you can get your password. And once Button1 is clicked (w/c means you are already authorized - correct time), a message box will appear showing something like,

> Your password is 111111.

And so on and so forth until all the passwords are used up, then it will be back to password 111111 again, 222222, 333333, etc... How do I do it? Like what time format? I'm having a hard time about the time comparison. Thanks.

Comment: You are indexing into he fifth element in a 4 element array FYI.  Your code sample will crash.

Comment: [How can I check if the current time is between in a time frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592248/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-time-is-between-in-a-time-frame)

Answer (score 2):

The function **isValidTime** checks time just on hours of the day.

You can wrap through your passwords using modular arithmetic as shown below.

The following works for me:

```
    private int currentPassword = -1;
    private int[] passwords = new int[]{111111,222222,333333,444444,555555};

    private DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2012, 7, 18, 22, 0, 0);
    private DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2012, 7, 18, 22, 15, 0);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValidTime(DateTime.Now))
        {
            currentPassword++;
            currentPassword = currentPassword % passwords.Length;

            MessageBox.Show(passwords[currentPassword].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Try again at a different time" );
        }
    }

    private bool isValidTime( DateTime now )
    {
        if ( startTime.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(now.TimeOfDay) <= 0)
        {
            if ( now.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(endTime.TimeOfDay) <= 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Just start a new windows form, add a button1, and this code should work.

Comment: It works just fine, but when I close the message box and try to get the next password (which is 222222), it is still 111111. Why's that?

Comment: @CantHandleMeBabe Are you by chance closing the program, instead of just closing the message box? Because, we increment the password each time before displaying a msgBox. If you want the currentPassword value to persist between application runs, mention it in your question.