# Working out rates using timespan in c#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to calculate different pay rates between certain hours.

For example: If someone works from 9am - 5pm they will recieve 1x rate.
if that same person works from 9am - 7pm they will get 1x rate from 9am-5pm and then 1.5x rate from 5pm - 7pm.

However, I am currently using a DateTime.Now for when they start work and a DateTime.Now when they finish the using a time span to calculate the hours in between.

I haven't tried anything because I dunno how to do it.

Comment: You have forgotten to ask a question. What's the issue?

Comment: If they work from 11 am to 7 pm, then what is the rate?  or if they work completely outside of 9 to 5, then what is their rate?   I think you need to define your rules more.

Comment: 1x between 7am and 5pm (No matter what) then
1.5x between 5pm and 7pm
So anything out side 7am -5 pm must be 1.5x rates so therefore(5pm -> 7am must be 1.5x rates)

Comment: "I haven't tried anything because I dunno how to do it.". Fine. What have you considered? What approaches did you think of? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have the beginning and end time stamp, but I just dunno how to set up the constraints to check if the worker gets overtime.

Comment: What don't you understand? Where are you stuck? What approaches did you consider?

Comment: ok so I have a beginning time and a end time.
I need to calculate how many hours the worker has worked for and if he has worked past 5pm then his rate needs to increase to 1.5x the hors he has worked. if the start ime was 7am and the start for overtime was 5pm but the worker worked until 7pm then he will have worked 10 hours at 1x rate and 2 hours at 1.5x rate. If I only have the 7am time stamp and the 7pm time stamp how would I go about calculating how much overtime was worked

Comment: Write all conditions above in the code in form of compilable "if(...)" in the question and highlight/comment places you have problem with. No code == no ability answer your question.

Comment: This [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592248/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-time-is-between-in-a-time-frame) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try:

```
static double Rate = 20.0; // 20$ per hour 9am to 5pm    

static double TotalPayment(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
  if (startTime > endTime)
    throw new ArgumentException("start must be before end");
  if (startTime.Date != endTime.Date)
    throw new NotImplementedException("start and end must be on same day");

  double totalHours = (endTime - startTime).TotalHours;

  double startOfOrdinaryRate = Math.Max(9.0, startTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);
  double endOfOrdinaryRate = Math.Min(17.0, endTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);
  double ordinaryHours;
  if (startOfOrdinaryRate > endOfOrdinaryRate)
    ordinaryHours = 0.0;
  else
    ordinaryHours = endOfOrdinaryRate - startOfOrdinaryRate;

  return 1.0 * Rate * ordinaryHours
    + 1.5 * Rate * (totalHours - ordinaryHours);
}
```

Do test if it works.