# How to check Date range based on midnight?

Tags: c#

Am trying to find the time range in between two time and calculated the time difference from midnight.

Eg:

```
StartDate1 : 13/02/2013 21.00
EndDate1:    13/02/2013 22.00.

StartDate2 : 13/02/2013 23.00
EndDate2:    14/02/2013 01.00.

1) am trying to find the time range, it falls in to midnight first ?
2) If yes then how much time difference from Midnight 
    e.g Day1= 2hrs (prior to midnight)
        Day2= 1hr (after midnight).
```

Any help please ?

I was looking at this question but not sure about it [TimeFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592248/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-time-is-between-in-a-time-frame)

Comment: Do you mean "is there a midnight within this range of date/time values"? Isn't that exactly the same as saying "is the start **date** later than the end **date**"?

Comment: true it says the time is fall under midnight but am trying to find how many hours before and after,is that make sense ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if there is a midnight between the times, just check if the dates are different:

```
if (startDate1.Date != endDate1.Date) {
  // there is at least one midnight between the times
}
```

If you know that there is never more than one midnight between the dates, then `endDate1.Date` is the time of that midnight. You can get the times before and after midnight using:

```
TimeSpan before = endDate1.Date - startDate1;
TimeSpan after = endDate1 - endDate1.Date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("13/02/2013 22.00");

 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("14/02/2013 01.00");

 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

Comment: Thanks @Roshana, this is just only give the total hours in between endtime to start time but am trying to find how many hours before midnight and how many hours after midnight.

Comment: TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime ); you get the output 3hrs but am trying to find here how many hours before (2hrs) midnight and how many hours after (1hr) midnight,is that make sense ?

Comment: If you know the total number of hours and the starting time of the process you can easily get the number of hours from the midnight no?

you just have to do little calculation to get that.
<br>
midnight - starting time = hours to midnight <br>
total hours - hours to midnight = hours after midnight <br>

there you have to have little more conditions and can get the final result easily

Comment: agree that, but i have 6 set of time sets (update my question above),that may not fall in to midnight

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan span = endTime - startTime;

Console.Writeline("Span: "+span);

Console.Writeline("Seconds: "+span.TotalSeconds);