# How to compare current time against time of day

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have an ASP.net page which has different hours of operation for different day. What I am looking to do is compare the current time against today's open to close hours. If the current server time falls within the open to close range display a "open.png" inside a div otherwise display a "close.png" inside a div.

Let's say I have two separate section in my `myfile.inc` file which is called from my main asp.net page:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 25px;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 85px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeader.png') no-repeat;">
        <br />
        210 Ave<br />
        White Plains, New York 10964<br />
        914.689.1542
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 80px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderMiddle.png') repeat-y;">
        <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; width: 260px; margin: 0 auto;">
            Monday & Thursday: 7AM - 7:30PM<br />
            Tuesday & Wednesday: 7AM - 7PM<br />
            Friday: 7AM - 5:30PM<br />
            Saturday: 8AM - 1:30PM <br />
            Sunday: Closed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 26px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderFooter.png') no-repeat;">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 25px;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 85px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeader.png') no-repeat;">
        <br />
        1 Road<br />
        Rye, New York 10630<br />
        914.325.8800    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 80px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderMiddle.png') repeat-y;">
        <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; width: 260px; margin: 0 auto;">
            Mon, Wed, & Fri: 8AM - 5:30PM<br />
            Tuesday & Thursday: 8AM - 6PM<br />
            Saturday: 8AM - 12PM <br />
            Sunday: Closed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 26px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderFooter.png') no-repeat;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The code of C# of what I have right now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class medical_specialties : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string time = now.ToString("T");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + time + "');", true);
    }
}
```

The above code just displays the current time.

How can I accomplish displaying the open and close image for both location based on the hours of operation comparing to the current time in C#?

Comment: Not related to your question, but why not move all those inline styles to an external stylesheet?

Comment: That is a great comment. When the page is ready and everything has been approved by execs I will be moving everything to external for easier editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the server side code to create two String variables that you can call from the client side using the server tags. Just place them in the url for the background. (I assume that's the location of the image you want to change).

```
public partial class medical_specialties : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String url1 = "theImages/ClosedHeaderMiddle.png";
    String url2 = "theImages/OpenHeaderMiddle.png";
    String location1URL = "";   //White Plains
    String location2URL = "";   //Rye
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string time = now.ToString("T");
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + time + "');", true);

            if(now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday){
                if(IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) )) {
                    location1URL = url2;
                    location2URL = url1;
                } else if(IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0)) {
                    location1URL = url2;
                    location2URL = url2;
                } else if(IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0)) {
                    location1URL = url2;
                    location2URL = url1;
                } else {
                    location1URL = url1;
                    location2URL = url1;
                }
            } else if(now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday) {
                ..... //just go on like the example above
            }

    }
}
```

//Credit: this following static function is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/592258/2777098 (@Daniel LeCheminant)

```
static public bool IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime time, 
                                      TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
{
    if (endTime == startTime)
    {
        return true;   
    }
    else if (endTime < startTime)
    {
        return time.TimeOfDay <= endTime ||
            time.TimeOfDay >= startTime;
    }
    else
    {
        return time.TimeOfDay >= startTime &&
            time.TimeOfDay <= endTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @IsabelHM Thank you for the code. For Location how do I get it? I have a medical_specialties.aspx page which is including another `myfile.inc` that has the information.

Comment: Try add an id to the div and add this: runat="server", then you can call it from the server side.

Comment: Because the DIV that I am trying to extract is inside the myotherfile.inc which is called by the aspc page, I am unable to use that DIV ID in the c# file. I have the following: `<div id="labHoursWP" runat="server">
 210 Avenue<br />
 White Plains, New York 10564<br />
</div>` and using the following line in my C# code: ` var wpInput = labHoursWP.InnerText;` I get the following error: `The name 'labHoursWP' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: give me a minute. I'll give you a sample code to try. Thnx

Comment: Everything else should be working once I get that part working I am sure.

Comment: Think it is working now. Weird! I will do some testing and update :) Thanks.